# Trouble with Index Matching two rows and one column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-match

I am attempting to `Index` and `Match` and find the green value labeled in my table below based on the criteria in the yellow cells.  Any idea how to go about this, here is my current formula:

```
INDEX($A$2:$F$31, MATCH($H$3,$B$2:$B$31,0), MATCH($H$4, $C$2:$C$31,0))
```

It keeps returning the "Type" and not the "Cats" value I would like to have, 0.1518.  Would `Vlookup` + `Match` be easier? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Basically, I am trying to match two row variables (City and Type) with the column variable (cats) to get the value.  However, if I use `vlookup` then maybe I can just say go to the cat column instead of matching it with another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(E2:E31,MATCH(1,INDEX((H3=B2:B31)*(H4=C2:C31),0,1),0))
```

Based on the non-array version of the formula found here: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria